# Where is the Pure-Ftp configuration?

Tags: ubuntu, configuration, pureftpd

It looks so confusing to me.

After OVH fire I'm re-installing Pure-Ftp in a new fresh and fireproof Ubuntu 20.10 server.

I discover that this new version has a single config file in **/etc/pure-ftpd/pure-ftp.conf**.
In my previous version all configuration was splitted in many small files in **/etc/pure-ftpd/config** folder.

Now the config folder still exists, then I cannot understand why I can overlap the configuration from a single file and splitted files and which one has the priority.
Moreover when I run pure-ftpd as service, it seems it is not looking at single configuration file.

Can someone help me to clarify how to configure the pure-ftpd service? Is it possibile to use the single configuration file for the systemd service?

Comment: usually it is possible that they include any config files im not using this ftpd but they often have to be the same configuration. however if you cant locate the files use dpkg -L install-name of package to see where it is installed

Comment: As far as I understand the single config file is completely ignored by the  daemon

Comment: `dpkg -L packagename` and update your question as its needed to keep helping you